# What are the best traffic pattern airspeeds in a Cessna 172N?

Tags: aircraft-performance, general-aviation, cessna-172

I have problems with my landings, and I would like to know what is the best speed
in the traffic pattern, especially on base and final? I am landing with 20 degrees flaps (in different weather conditions), and to be honest as a student pilot I am confused by the Cessna 172N POH, can anyone help?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what has your instructor said?

Comment: Have you read the POH? The recommended speeds are in there. What are you confused about in it?

Comment: Baseleg = 70 kts, Final  = 65 kts.

Comment: Section 4 of POH - Normal Procedures:

Comment: Section 4-3  of 172N POH - Normal procedures,  Speeds for normal Operation, Landing Approach: Normal Approach flaps up  60-70 KIAS, Normal Approach, flaps 40 degrees 55-65 KIAS, Short Field Approach, Flaps 40 degrees 60 KIAS, Balked Landing Maximum Power, Flaps 20 degrees 55 KIAS.  What is Normal Approach?  Base, Final ? In which weather conditions these speeds are valid? , For example: No winds, 40 degrees Celsius,  No winds  0 degrees Celsius?  Can  you understand confusion of student pilot when he/she hear question "Have you read POH" ?

Comment: The POH doesn't mention wind or temperature so you should assume no wind and disregard temperature. Wind really doesn't matter though as the speed is air speed. The only time you want to account for wind speed is if there are gusts, then you add half the gust speed to your air speed. Normal approach is just that, normal. The other types of approach are short field or soft field.

Comment: I'll echo @Notts90's comment above; **have you discussed this with your instructor? What did he/she say?** If you are finding the POH confusing, then it might not be a bad idea to schedule a session where you just sit down with your instructor and the two of you go through the POH without touching any of the knobs and switches in the actual airplane. You'll be expected to be familiar with the POH no later than by the time of your checkride, so might as well work on figuring it out now.

Comment: You guys must fly different planes than I do because none of the Owner's Handbooks that I have say anything about speeds and flaps in different parts of the traffic pattern. The general rule that we follow is to cross the threshold at 1.3 Vso and full flaps and manage your speeds, gear, and flaps in the pattern to reach that number. Short field is a bit slower.

Comment: Assuming 30 degree flags, cross the fence at 60-65 knots, touchdown at 60

Answer (score 1):

This is really something you should discuss with your instructor, but if you want some *general guidance* then this should work:

- Downwind: 70kts, 10° flaps
- Base: 65kt, 20° flaps
- Final: 60kts, 30° flaps

I say "guidance" because you may need to adjust this but it is in line with the POH values that you quoted in your comment and FWIW it's what I would use 'by default' in an unfamiliar C172. Although personally I wouldn't use 40° of flaps unless it's a short-field landing: the aircraft will come down more quickly with them fully extended.

But I'm not an instructor and I don't want to make assumptions about what he's teaching you and why, so you should definitely ask him this question. Ask him what power setting (RPM) he recommends on each leg, too.